# How to find 2 lines given only points?

Tags: computer-vision, regression

I have this image:

[image]

Humans can tell that two lines can be fitted through the points.  A naive algorithm would put a horizontal best fit line.  Is there an algorithm that best fits a series of points while ignoring distant outliers?

Comment: How much points do you have?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson The function will be given at least 15 points before it starts execution.

Answer (score 1):

There are robust estimation techniques to fit a model to noisy data, such as [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC).  You would need to fit one line, exclude all the points that belong to that line, and the fit the second line to the remaining points.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from [David Forsyth web page](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/CS543ComputerVision/Week%207/Fitting.pdf) (author of the book: Forsyth, David A. and Jean Ponce (2002). *Computer Vision: A Modern Approach.* Prentice
Hall Professional Technical Reference) the following is Algorithm 15.2:

> Hypothesize *k* lines (perhaps uniformly at random)
>
> *or*
>
> hypothesize an assignment of lines to points and then fit lines using
>   this assignment
>
> ```
> Until convergence
>    allocate each point to the closest line
>    refit lines
> end
> ```

In your case *k* is 2.

Answer (score 1):

The Hough transform is suitable for this task. Basically, each point votes for the existence of all lines that pass through it (in a line-parameter-space, e.g. rho-theta for distance from origin and angle). If the parameter space is discretized, then you'll get peaks for each of the lines present in your data. The outliers will have voted for parameters that have little votes from other points, so they will have low count in the parameter-space.

The image below (from Wikipedia) illustrates the concept in the ideal case (the points actually lie on exact lines). With read data, the peaks will be fuzzier, but you'll still be able to distinguish them from the outliers. The pros of this method is that you do not have to hypothesize how many lines there are, and it works well for many types of images/data. The cons are that it may fail if there are many non-linear distractors, such as in natural scenes containing many curved objects.

[image]